# TeXstudio: How to associate tex syntax color scheme to non tex file?

Tags: texstudio

In TeXstudio I want to associate different files with tex coloring scheme.
For example, I open **.stex** file and the syntax is not colored. This **.stex** file is the same tex file, I just renamed it for some reason.

I've putted **.stex** extension in my ini file:

```
 Files\Default%20File%20Filter=TeX files (*.tex *.bib *.sty *.cls *.mp
 ***.stex**)
```

But it does nothing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I guess, you tried to highlight the `.stex` in the ini entry, but as you can see the markup does not work there. If you added this extension in an own line, then this is very likely the cause of the issue. On the other hand in the file to be highlighted there must some known code that can be highlighted.

Comment: Of course ini file line looks: Files\Default%20File%20Filter=TeX files (*.tex *.bib *.sty *.cls *.mp
 *.stex). As I said, that file is tex file, with latex syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually change the current highlighting under `View -> Highlighting`.

The automatic assignment of file extensions to coloring schemes (and parsing functionality) is not user-editable.

You may file a feature request at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/