# Enable TeXstudio's syntax highlighting for custom file extensions

Tags: texstudio

My template makes me use files with file extension ".def". They contain regular tex code. How can I enable syntax highlighting in TeXstudio for these files?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can at least set it for one file with View --> Set highlighting, not sure about using it generally for .def-files.

Comment: Just found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97191/texstudio-how-to-associate-tex-syntax-color-scheme-to-non-tex-file which is a duplicate of your question. If you agree, we'll close your question.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for "texstudio syntax highlighting" and did not find that question (and still do not). So I vote to leave this question.

Comment: Answer: The automatic assignment of file extensions to coloring schemes (and parsing functionality) is not user-editable.

Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97191/texstudio-how-to-associate-tex-syntax-color-scheme-to-non-tex-file